# How to link domain name with my VPS server

Tags: server, dns, hosting, vps

I have purchase my domain and purchase VPS windows from anther company ,
I publish my website to my IIS server on my vps and I can access it from anywhere by ip ,
how can I link my domain name to my vps server to open by domain name
Exp:
my domain name is example.com
my vps ip is 25.100.12.xx

I cant access my website by ip http://25.100.12.xx/ how can I access it by domain name http://example.com/

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup an A record in your DNS file which you should be able to do with the company that you have registered your domain with.
In their Control Panel somewhere the should be an option to add/modify your DNS entries.
To access your site as example.com you will need to set/change a record as such:

```
    Host = @ (or empty depending on the provider)
    Type = A
    IP Address = 25.100.12.xx
```

If you also want to allow access to your site via [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) you will need to add an additional record as follows:

```
    Host = www
    Type = A
    IP Address = 25.100.12.xx
```

If you then want to add any other addresses to go to the same IP Address you will need to do the same for them too.